# Haskell getting a string from list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm going through Learn You A Haskell. I have a following function:

```
bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => a -> a-> String
bmiTell weight height
  | bmi <= skinny ="underweight"
  | bmi <= normal = "ok"
  | bmi <= fat = "fat"
  | otherwise = "whale"
  where
    bmi = weight/height^2
    (skinny,normal,fat)=(18.5, 25.0,30.0)
```

which works perfectly fine. I'm now making a list comprehension, where
a desired result is something like this:

> [(68, "underweight"),(69,"ok"),(70,"ok")]

this is my ghci input:

```
[(x,y)| x <-[68..70], y <- bmiTell x 185]
```

and the output is

> [(68.0,'u'),(68.0,'n'),(68.0,'d'),(68.0,'e'),(68.0,'r'),(68.0,'w'),(68.0,'e'),(68.0,'i'),(68.0,'g'),(68.0,'h'),(68.0,'t'),(69.0,'u'),(69.0,'n'),(69.0,'d'),(69.0,'e'),(69.0,'r'),(69.0,'w'),(69.0,'e'),(69.0,'i'),(69.0,'g'),(69.0,'h'),(69.0,'t'),(70.0,'u'),(70.0,'n'),(70.0,'d'),(70.0,'e'),(70.0,'r'),(70.0,'w'),(70.0,'e'),(70.0,'i'),(70.0,'g'),(70.0,'h'),(70.0,'t')]

I tried making it a (x,[y]), but I get the same result with Chars in ""s instead of single quotes

Comment: Just use `[ (x, bmiTell x 185) | x <- [68..70] ]`

Comment: Indeed, thank you, may I have your answer please? *so embarassed*

Comment: Put bmiTell X 185 in a list [bmiTell X 185] and your's should work. Remember, strings are lists. The comprehension was pull}ng from the only list it found. Also, two generators in a comprehension are aXb or Cartesian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `map` function:

```
map (\w -> (w, bmiTell w 185)) [68..70]
```

Or as @ErikR mentioned, using list comprehension:

```
[ (x, bmiTell x 185) | x <- [68..70] ]
```